# JavaFX Initialize function and things in there

Tags: java, javafx

Is it a proper way to locate ContextMenu, setCellValueFactory, setRowFactory, etc. in `initialize` function?

```
public void initialize() {
         ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
         MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("Cut");
         MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
         MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
         contextMenu.getItems().addAll(cut, copy, paste);



         empId.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().employeeIdProperty().asObject());
         empName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
         empLastName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

         //Show info when double clicked
         employeeTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
             TableRow<Employee> row = new TableRow<>();
             row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                 if(!row.isEmpty() && event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                     Employee emp = row.getItem();

                     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                     loader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/ViewEmployeeView.fxml"));
                     try {
                        loader.load();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     ViewEmployeeController viewEmployee = loader.getController();
                     viewEmployee.setText(emp.getFirstName(), emp.getLastName(), emp.getEmail(), emp.getPhoneNumber(), String.valueOf(emp.getSalary()), String.valueOf(emp.getManagerId()), String.valueOf(emp.getDepartmentId()));


                     Parent root = loader.getRoot();
                     Stage stage = new Stage();
                     stage.setTitle("View employee");
                     stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                     stage.initOwner(addBtn.getScene().getWindow());
                     stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                     stage.show();
                     stage.setResizable(false);

                 } else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                     row.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
                 }
             });
             return row;
         });
```

I don't know If I clarified my thoughts right but here is the example to understand me better:
I create FXML with different buttons(with OnClicked methods), fields, labels, etc. Then I generate FXML controller where OnClicked methods are generated as well. But what If I need to add additional things as ContextMenu, rowFactory, make dynamic columns for TableView or add setOnAction event, let's say for MenuItem in ContextMenu. Where should I write those things? Is initialize function acceptable for this need?

Comment: Based on what I gather from your question... yes. It is acceptable. There isn’t a set-in-stone practice for initialization. It’s usually whatever the programmer feels is cleanest and easiest to manage.

Comment: The `initialize()` method is pretty much *designed* for that use case.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. That's what I wanted to know.